# Sonarqube integration with codecommit not working

Tags: java, sonarqube, aws-codecommit

I want to integrate sonarqube with codecommit. My sonarqube server is running on one linux server. I want to analyze my code using sonarqube as soon as someone check-in the code in codecommit. How can I integrate the same.

I installed sonarqube on ubuntu server. I tried putting env variable as sonar authentication and url into project yaml file and also put `mvn sonar:sonar` command in build or post build section but it got failed.

```
env:
  variables:
    SONAR_LOGIN: "MY_SONARQUBE_AUTHTOKEN"
    SONAR_HOST: "MY_SONARQUBE_URL"
    #You should use parameter-store here instead

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - mvn test
  post_build:
    commands:
      - mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_LOGIN -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST
```

It should give the result on sonarqube page but it is unable to find `mvn sonar:sonar` command getting failed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. You need to provide more relevant (logging and version) information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue, but make sure you've installed maven into your ubuntu CodeBuild container.

```
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: openjdk11

  commands:
  - apt-get install -y maven
```

Also, make sure you've added the SonarScanner plugin into your settings.xml

```
<settings>
<pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- Optional URL to server. Default value is http://localhost:9000 -->
            <sonar.host.url>
              http://myserver:9000
            </sonar.host.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
 </profiles>
```

Setup source: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/